# Why Custom UIRefreshControl Class's Background Color not changing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I created custom UIRefreshControl as below:

```
class CustRefreshCont: UIRefreshControl {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        let blueColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue
        let lightGrayColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray

        self.tintColor = blueColor
        self.backgroundColor = lightGrayColor

        self.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Updating data", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : self.tintColor, NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor : self.backgroundColor!])
    }
}
```

And way I assign UIRefreshControl from UIViewController is copied below:

```
    let refreshControl = CustRefreshCont()
```

Text and the ActivityIndicator customizations are being displayed, however the background color is showing as black.

Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Comment: So tintColor and backgroundColor are not correctly displayed right ?

Comment: tintColor is displayed correctly. Just background color of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your configuration code to the initializer. I don't think the `draw` method is the correct place to do it.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    backgroundColor = .red
    tintColor = .blue
}
```